# How do I print an image to a fixed size over multiple pages?

Tags: printing, images, gimp, imagemagick

I want to print an image that is 52x44 cm using letter sized pages in Windows 10.  So it's similar to this question, but I need to print an image that is larger than one page. Presumably it will take 2x2 pages.
[How do I print an image at actual size?](https://superuser.com/questions/378814/how-do-i-print-an-image-at-actual-size)

So far I've tried setting a fixed image size in Paint and Gimp, but it hasn't worked and I'm wasting a lot of toner.

Answer (score 1):

Among other methods [it is suggested](https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-make-pictures-print-larger) to cut the image into pieces with `gimp` and print them separately

1. Open the image in GIMP by clicking `File-> Open`
2. Select `View-> Show Grid` and check this option.
3. Select `Image-> Configure Grid`. Select the Line Style from the drop-down menu. Enter the Spacing dimensions of each segment, making them no larger than the paper size. Leave the Offset at zero pixels. Click `OK.`
4. Use the Rectangle Select tool. Select the first segment. Copy the segment by clicking <kbd>CTRL+C</kbd>.
5. Press <kbd>CTRL+N</kbd> to make a new image. Enter the image dimensions that match the size of the segment you copied. [You can use a size bigger than needed, and after you pasted (6) you can use `Image->Crop to content` option]
6. Paste into the new image with <kbd>CTRL+V</kbd>
7. Select `File > Print` and select the printer, change options...

Repeat this process (4-7) for each image segment.

**Notes**

- Note that you can find a printer that automatically does this job for you, install the printer drivers (you don't really have to buy the printer) and print to file by selecting this software/driver.  [Here](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Mobile-Printing-Cloud-Printing/Printer-Keeps-splitting-my-work-across-several-pages-when-I/td-p/8431947) a user complains because the printer (HP DeskJet 3762 All-in-One Printer) keeps dividing his job into multiple pages; you can see if that printer driver (or another) is also able to *print to file*, then you can print each single file...
- Or you can use `imagemagick` and write a [command line to split](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9648047/3569208) your image...

Comment: I might have to use this method.  I wish there was an easier way!

Comment: Take a look at different printer models, the best models often have better drivers and software... They may print the way you want by default. IMHO it's the simplest and most practical solution. And they can print to file (e.g. separate pdf files or more pages in the same file). Then you can print the pdf(s) with your usual printer. Check first with a print preview to make sure you're not wasting any toner or ink, set page margins to zero etc etc... Magic word for further search may be *tiling filter* for gimp... Good luck. ps> You can modify the _printing size_ in gimp, if needed.